# Nested additional_lookup

Tags: python, eve

I am trying to find a solution to search through two nested fields(Search field 1 and 2) in mongodb and list all documents matching them. Unable to find any relevant resource.

I am using Python eve to make a REST API for interacting with mongodb

```
identifiers = {
    'url' : "articles/identifiers",
    'datasource':{
        'source' : 'articles',
    },
    'id_field' : 'extracted_information' ,
    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': 'regex("[\w:]+")',
        'field': 'extracted_information.participant_b'
    },
    'schema': {
        'extracted_information': {
            'type': 'dict',
            'schema':{
                'participant_a':{
                    'type':'dict',
                    'schema':{
                        'identifier':{ # Search field 1
                            'type' : 'string'
                        }
                    }
                },
                'participant_b':{
                    'type':'dict',
                    'schema':{
                        'identifier':{ # Search field 2
                            'type' : 'string'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you searching for, additional key,value ..?

Comment: I have to search in the following fields and list all documents matching either of them:
`extracted_information.participant_a.identifier` and `extracted_information.participant_b.identifier`
It can be done using where, but I will have to do it as endpoint, like api/v1/indentifier/<identityKey>
Thanks

Comment: In your scenario, can you have a query parameter to use it as filter like `api/v1/identifiers?search_key=<identityKey>`?. If so, there's a way using text index and an event hooks I believe.

Comment: I am asked to make it as endpoint, query parameter where is always available